# Directories are full, with 200+GB free on disk that is partitioned

Tags: storage, lvm, fedora, luks

I am running Fedora 30 (new to this distro), and can't seem to use all the available space on an encrypted partition. There are only two partitions of sda for a total of 300GB, 1 with 1GB and 2 299GB, with 1 being boot and 2 being everything else. sda2 is encrypted and was setup with LVM.

When running df -h I can see the sizes that are allocated to each directory:

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                 7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    7.9G   72M  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    7.9G  9.2M  7.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                    7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/fedora-root   15G   13G  2.1G  87% /
tmpfs                    7.9G   24K  7.9G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1                976M  167M  742M  19% /boot
tmpfs                    1.6G   52K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Looking in gparted I can see that all 299GB are allocated to the sda2 partition. Also seen in /dev/mapper is a luk directory, and I know that that is related to the disk-encryption but I'm not sure how.

fdisk -l output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 300 GiB, 322122547200 bytes, 629145600 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x18ffed28

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048   2099199   2097152    1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       2099200 629145599 627046400  299G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/mapper/luks-1a41761b-c234-4fee-9c8d-5464c79c71d9: 299 GiB, 321030979584 bytes, 627013632 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-root: 15 GiB, 16106127360 bytes, 31457280 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-swap: 7.9 GiB, 8497659904 bytes, 16596992 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

I have also tried using lvextend/resize2fs to give more storage to /dev/mapper/fedora-root without success.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong, or am misunderstanding about this process or what is happening here. Thank you for your help!

EDIT

vgs and lvs ouputs by request of a deleted comment. Volume sizes are a little messed up from some experimentation but same situation as before.

```
VG     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree  
  fedora   1   2   0 wz--n- 298.98g <54.07g
  LV   VG     Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
```

```
root fedora -wi-ao---- 237.00g                                                    
swap fedora -wi-ao----   7.91g
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: better do backups before performing potentially dangerous operations, like resizing a filesystem for the first time.

Your `fedora-root` LV has a size of 237.00g, but your `/` filesystem has a size of 15g. This means that the very last step to increase available size was not done.

For an *xfs* filesystem, to use all available partition or LV space that would simply be:

```
# xfs_growfs /
```

In case the default *xfs* wasn't chosen, each filesystem has its own specific method to increase its size. For example, with an *ext4* filesystem that would be instead:

```
# resize2fs /dev/mapper/fedora-root
```

Both are working (or must be done) online. Be warned that *xfs* can't be shrunk back at all and that *ext4* can't be shrunk online, only offline which is quite difficult for the root filesystem.

For an other time: the `lvresize` command has a `--resizefs` option which can perform both actions in a single command.

Comment: Thanks A.B! xfs_growfs was what I needed to extend the volume for the directories.

Comment: @Techaeth that is more accurately: to extend the filesystem to fit and use all the available space in the logical volume containing it.